# condition.wait() in a "with" block or self.acquire and self.release?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multithreading

When using a condition variable, is it bad practice to use a `with` statement?

I know that `condition.wait()` releases the lock but does this behavior change if it's being called inside a `with` block?

```
class BlockingQueue:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.max_size = size
        self.queue = deque()
        self.condition = Condition()

    # if there are already x items in queue, should block
    def enqueue(self, item):
        with self.condition:
            while len(self.queue) == self.max_size:
                self.condition.wait()
            self.queue.append(item)
            self.condition.notify_all()
```

Comment: What is `Condition()`? Do you mean [`asyncio.Condition`](https://docs.python.org/library/asyncio-sync.html?highlight=condition#asyncio.Condition)? Please show your imports.

Comment: @Chris: Most likely it's a `threading.Condition` based on the question's tags (always a good place to check to disambiguify terms).

Comment: @martineau, a [mre] is always prefereable. Sure, we can guess based on context and tags, but we shouldn't hvae to.

Comment: @Chris: Unfortunately we live in an imperfect world. Besides, leaving `import`s out of code is an accepted practice here.

Comment: @martineau, we may live in an imperfect world, but I can still ask for clarification in a comment. I disagree that leaving imports out is "accepted". Clarity is always worth striving for.

Comment: @Chris: Never said you couldn't ask for clarification — I was merely pointing out that there really wasn't any ambiguity since the OP clearly indicated they were using the `threading` module when they asked their question (via its tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Condition` object [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) says in part:

> A condition variable obeys the [context management protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#with-locks): using the `with` statement acquires the associated lock for the duration of the enclosed block. The `acquire()` and `release()` methods also call the corresponding methods of the associated lock.

So, yes, they work fine with a `with` statement. In fact that's the preferred way to make use of them.